# How to remove an element from array by value in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have this simple program in Julia:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30]
delete!(a, 10)
```

but it does not work. The error is `MethodError: no method matching delete!(::Array{Int64,1}, ::Int64)`

I can see that `deleteat!` and `splice!` accept the index and not the value.

How to remove element `10` from array `a` in Julia?

Comment: Do you want to remove element `10` in the array, or do you want to remove the element with a value of `10`?

Comment: Isn't it the same thing? I want the array to be `a = [1, 2, 3, 20, 30]`.

Comment: How do you want multiple occurences to be handled? To remove all `10`s, you could use `filter!(x -> x != 10, a)`.

Comment: Say I don't have multiple occurrences.

Comment: `(idx = findfirst(a,10))>0 ? deleteat!(a,idx) : a` also an option (works when `10` appears only once. Of course, `10` should be replaced by a variable and this made into a function. The `filter!` solution would be clearer though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `filter!` function to filter in the value `10`. The `≠` (type `\ne` and press `TAB`) comes in handy!.

```
julia> a = [1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30]
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
  2
  3
 10
 20
 30

julia> filter!(x->x≠10,a)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
  2
  3
 20
 30

julia>
```

The solution will even work if you have multiple 10 in the array.

```
julia> a = [1,10,10]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
 10
 10

julia> filter!(x->x≠10,a)
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
```

Comment: Just noting again, `deleteat!(a,findfirst(a,10))` is >30% faster but works only to delete the first element equal to 10 (and errors if no such element, but this can be fixed). It might be relevant as it might be in a critical code section.

Comment: Also useful if you only want to delete one instance of the element, not all instances. The syntax has also changed and you now need to use `findfirst(x->x==10, a)`.  The predicate function construction probably has not insignificant overhead so this might account for some of that performance difference, on top of breaking the loop early after the first occurrence.

Answer (score 12):

From the documentation of `deleteat!`

> `deleteat!(a::Vector, inds)`
>
> Remove the items at the indices given by `inds`, and return the modified `a`. Subsequent items are shifted to fill the resulting gap.
>
> `inds` can be either an iterator or a collection of sorted and unique integer indices, **or a boolean vector of the same length as `a` with true indicating entries to delete**.

<sup>(emphasis mine).</sup>

I.e., you can simply test for (elementwise) equality, and use this for 'boolean indexing' as with normal arrays:

```
deleteat!(a, a .== 10);
```

---

<sub>PS: or if you only want to delete the first one: deleteat!(a, findfirst(a .== 10));</sub>